# storing entries in a Java map, in LIFO order

Tags: java, dictionary

I'm trying to achieve something like a LinkedHashMap, with entries added in the top, rather than in the bottom (LIFO). I don't want to sort it afterwards, just looking for an implementation that allows exactly that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a "StackHashMap", this can probably help you:

http://www.koders.com/java/fidA648AB05902E307E4CDD11A20D41499984C495AE.aspx?s=IHandler

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I was hoping to find a more formal code (AKA com.apache.org or something similar). Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you are better off using two collections to make things clearer, esp. when you are doing something unusual. In this case, a Deque (which doesn't have to be synchronized/thread safe) or Stack (which is synchronized) with a Map may be the best option.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this solution. However, as there's no existing implementation of Stack HashMap that I know of, this solution makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for a Stack?

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

Answer (score 0):

The Java [`Stack`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) class is a LIFO queue.